# Equal line spacing in tabularx?

Tags: formatting, titles, tabularx, titlesec

I'm using tabularx to make a nice chapter title (probably not the way to go, but the easiest for me to align stuff).

1. How do I make the title line spacing equal? (The letter "g" messes up the spacing), also why is the title not horizontally aligned?
2. Is there a better way to achieve this effect without using tabularx? Big chapter number on the right aligned at the bottom, while the title is underlined and multilined?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor} 


\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L r@{}} 
{\Huge \sffamily \textbf {#1}}\vspace{0.2em} & 
{\normalfont\sffamily\fontsize{120}{110}\selectfont\color{gray!25}{\textbf \thechapter}} \\\cline{1-1}
\end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ace ace ace ace ace ace ace age ace ace ace ace ace ace ace }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should put the `\Huge` before the \begin{tabular} so that the standard line spacing fits.

Comment: this is unrelated to tabular `{\Huge \sffamily \textbf {#1}}` sets Huge text on a nornalsize baseline as you end the size xhange with `}` before the end of the paragraph

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you change

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L r@{}} 
{\Huge \sffamily \textbf {#1}}\vspace{0.2em} &
```

to

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}L r @{}} 
#1 &
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{
%\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L r@{}} 
%{\Huge \sffamily \textbf {#1}}\vspace{0.2em} & 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}L r @{}} 
#1 & 
{\normalfont\sffamily \fontsize{120}{110}\selectfont \color{gray!25}{\textbf \thechapter}} \\\cline{1-1}
\end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ace ace ace ace ace ace ace age ace ace ace ace ace ace ace}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd not use `tabularx`, but a top aligned `\parbox` that contains a bottom aligned `\parbox` with the title, the vertical skip and the rule. This way the chapter number will be aligned with the bottom line of the title.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\jakechapter{\thechapter}}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\jakechapter{\hphantom{0}}}

\newsavebox{\jakechapterbox}
\newcommand{\jakechapter}[2]{%
  \sbox{\jakechapterbox}{\normalfont\fontsize{120}{110}\sffamily\bfseries\color{gray!25}#1}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\jakechapterbox-2\tabcolsep}{%
    \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{%
      \raggedleft\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries#2%
    }
    \vspace{0.2em}\hrule
  }\hfill\usebox{\jakechapterbox}%
}


\begin{document}

\begingroup\let\clearpage\relax\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\chapter*{Introduction}

\chapter{This is a chapter title split across two lines}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

The `\begingroup...\endgroup` business is for producing a single image with two chapter titles, one numbered and the other unnumbered.

The second picture shows that the baselines of the title and of the chapter number agree.

[image]

[image]